# importing equation images

Tags: copy-paste

I'm currently writing a summary of a paper, and to make things easier for me, I decided to just use the windows snipping tool, to copy the equations from the paper, and insert them in my latex summary using includegraphics. Unfortunally these equations turn up ugly when compiled, though the font is the same. They look blurry. I tried shifting from .png to .eps and even .pdf, but nothing works.

Does anyone know what I can do?

Thanks!

I don't have the latex code for the equations, only the paper as pdf

Comment: why you not copy the code from your paper? it is simpler than insert images of equations ... and require less effort! welcome to the site!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: If you show us the equations, maybe someone would help you typesetting them in LaTeX... Also, it is sometimes possible to find the LaTeX source for articles, it certainly is on arXiv.

Comment: @marsupilam: I doubt that a photograph of the screen content by smartphone or digital camera would be better than using the screen shot utility provided by the OS or graphics programmes.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sorry, I was being goofy, I'll delete the sarcasm.

Comment: @marsupilam: Didn't catch the sarcasm. Please markup your sarcastic comments ;-)

Comment: retyping of equation has some benefits (as follows from your edited question), not just (as you see temporary) unnecessary work: you will able to use this equation latter, you will become mote familiar with them and you maybe after then see some their new aspect, you will improve your LaTeX skills ... their retyping can be very educative. short way is nor always the best (really short) way :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use windows snipping tool, you'll end up with the resolution of your screen, and you lose a lot in terms of quality. You could use the snipping tool or a print screen when really zoomed in to get a higher resolution, but the resulting bitmap will still have a lower quality than what you started with, since that was most likely a PDF containing a vector image.

To maintain the high vector resolution, you can crop the PDF itself with a program capable of editing PDF files. I know that [Inkscape (free)](https://inkscape.org/en/) and probably [Adobe Illustrator (not free)](http://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator.html) can do this, but there may be other alternatives. All in all, depending on how complex the equations are, it may be simpler and even better-looking to just retype the equations, as the comments already mention.